# https for an rails app on not-standard port within the same apache server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, https, centos

I have an existing apache server with `https` handling traffic for `https://www.example.com`.

How can I config rails (and apache) to handle `https` requests from another port, e.g. `https://www.example.com:6000/api/v1/datafeed/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Apache proxy with balancer module.  Here is how I configured rails behind Apache 2.4 with NamedVirtualHost:

Enable the following modules in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so​
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so​
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so​
```

And something like following for your VirtualHost configuration

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:6000 https

<VirtualHost *:6000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName www.example.com

DocumentRoot "rails_root/public"
<Directory "rails_root/public"
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

 ProxyPass / balancer://myapp_cluster/
 ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myapp_cluster/
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyVia On

 <Proxy balancer://myapp_cluster>
     # Note the port here, this should be the port where your rails app is running.
     BalancerMember http://localhost:3000
 </Proxy>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
 SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/ssl/certificate_file.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/ssl/certificate_key.key"

 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error.log" 
 CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access.log" combined
 </VirtualHost>
```